# Looking for a solution that integrates Gravity Forms and Amazon S3

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

TL;DR: We're looking for a solution that would store files uploaded via Gravity Forms in a custom Amazon S3 environment, preferably direct.

Longer version: We have a somewhat complicated multi-page form created with Gravity Forms. One of the fields allows the user to attach up to 5 files via the multiple file upload field, which should then be stored on an in-house Amazon S3 instance (to simplify, it basically uses a custom address instead of .s3.amazonaws.com). Best case scenario would be that uploaded files never even touch the filesystem of the server the site is running on.
The only solutions we've found seem to offer this only as an extension of storing EVERYTHING, including files uploaded into the Media Library, in S3, which we specifically don't want to do. So far we haven't found anything which would allow us to specifically only upload files attached via Gravity Forms to S3.

Does anyone have any suggestions on if this is possible, preferably with links?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using my [Gravity Forms Media Library](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-media-library/) plugin to automatically import files uploaded via Gravity Forms to the WordPress Media Library and the [WP Offload S3 Lite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/) plugin to automatically upload files imported into the media library to Amazon S3.

Comment: Sidenote.... that is a premium plugin, i.e. it is not free. Amazing features though.